# Kibana Error Alerting - Filter Similiar Error Messages | Similarity Query [Elastalert]

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, alert, elastalert

My goal is to be alerted for unique error *types* only (Elasticsearch 6.8 + [Elastalert](https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert)).

Example error logs (5 documents, same index, same field):

- Error 9837 in Component X trying to reconnect in 9.3 seconds
- Error 9837 in Component X trying to reconnect in 8.7 seconds
- Attempt to connect to 19.324.21.234 failed
- 2021/01/01 08:51:54.203 Errno 111 tensorflow/stream_executor...
- 2021/01/01 08:52:76.009 Errno 111 tensorflow/stream_executor...

Using `query_key` from [Elastalert](https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ruletypes.html#query-key) I can make sure to be alerted for unique error messages only. The error messages above are all unique and therefore I will receive 5 alerts. However I only want to receive 3 alerts, one per error *type*.

Elastalert allows you to write regular queries with Elasticsearch's Query DSL.

**Is there a way to write a query which filters out documents if a specific field is 100% - 90% similiar to other documents?**

I suspect there might be a totally different solution to this. If there are better ways to handle alerting or some best practices, feel free to share them.

Answer (score 0):

One can add a new field with the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)